# Sending push notifications from one device to another in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an iOS application in which user orders an item, when the order ready, the vendor is supposed to inform the user via push notification. 
My question is, is it possible to send push notification from one device to another?

For this purpose I want to use FCM. I read that they allow two sorts of messages.

1. Downstream, messages from server to device.
2. Upstream, messages from device to server.

Will upstream messages serve the purpose according to my requirement? If so, how am I supposed to implement them?

Comment: If you really need upstream messages read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream But I'd consider your backend logic + normal downstream notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you were using `Firebase`, so for `every registered` users there is an ssociated `device token id` save into some collection right. (Registering flow)

Let's say you were using `cloud functions` (a vague definition would be function that are running into serverless architecture, and they get executed when there are called)

so you'd call this function from your app via **HTTP** with **Post Method**

logic:

```
  - extract that http request 
  - who is sending the message (uid, message)

  - who needs to receive that message (someone) 
  - query that someone's device token id and save it to recipient_device_token_id
  - construct to push notification payload (message)
  - send push notification for recipients using its recipient_device_token_id
  - end the http response
```

Voila, I am sure there is other way of doing it, but this extracting all the logic from your app to the cloud.